# foreach where data flips sides every other

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to say: if the image is on the left the next one should be on the right, repeat until done?

Pseudo code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    if (previous class=imageLeft)
    {
        <div class="imageRight">Right Image</div>
        <div>Left Content</div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="imageLeft">Left Image</div>
        <div>Right Content</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? We aren't compilers.

Comment: @Magus The `if` block is clearly pseudocode.  That's the line he doesn't know how to implement.

Comment: @Servy: That's not my point. This question shows no attempts, thereby becoming a code request.

Comment: @Magus He condensed his actual problem down to the point where he got to the one single component that he couldn't solve himself.  That's entirely appropriate for a question.  He's not asking how to display all of his items using a given format; he has attempted to do this, but run into a specific problem *with his attempt* that he cannot solve.  When he reached the point that he could no longer make progress on his own, he asked on SO.  The question, as it is, is not so broad as to be unanswerable; it is in fact quite specific.  Seems fine to me.  (And I generally have *very* high standards.)

Comment: And @Servy 's point is proven now that the question has an accepted answer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. You're pseudo code is almost there. Just use a variable to hold the value and remember to update its value in each iteration:

```
@int c = 0;
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    if (c == 0)
    {
        <div class="imageRight">Right Image</div>
        <div>Left Content</div>
        c = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="imageLeft">Left Image</div>
        <div>Right Content</div>
        c = 0;
    }
}
```

alternatively, you can use `@foreach (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)` loop and then use `i % 2` to get the even/odd row numbers and apply the class as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create a helper for this. The helper keeps the code clean and makes inner loops much easier to handle. Starts to save you some time once your applications grow in size, especially if you copy a working example. Here's mine:

```
public class LooperHelper
{
    private int Iterations { get; set; } = 0;
    public void AddTick() {
        Iterations++;
    }
    public int GetTicks()
    {
        return Iterations;
    }
    public bool DivisibleBy(int divisor)
    {
        return (Iterations % divisor == 0);
     }
    public string ConditionalOutput(string stringoutput, int divisor, bool reverse = false)
    {
        return ((Iterations % divisor == 0) == !reverse ? stringoutput : "");
    }
}
```

This allows you to do nested conditional formatting based on the number of iterations:

```
var outerloophelper = new LooperHelper();
var innerloophelper = new LooperHelper();
foreach (var product in products)
{
    outerloophelper.AddTick();
    <div class="row @(outerloophelper.ConditionalOuput("alternative", 2, true))">
        @foreach (var subproduct in product.SubProducts)
        {
            innerloophelper.AddTick();
            <div class="4u@(innerloophelper.ConditionalOutput("$", 3)) 12u$(small)"> 
                 @subproduct.ToString()
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

In the above example, every second product  is decorated with the class "alternative" (where the first is marked alternative as reverse is set true). The nested sub-product items are further decorated with the addition of a $ sign to the class to denote the change of the row for every third column. But you can do also other nifty things, such as making sure that a hr-tag is added in between, but not after the final looped element, like in the following example:

```
@if (!outerloophelper.DivisibleBy(products.Count())) { <hr />}
```

In short, when initialising the helper, it begins with 0 and positioning the AddTick() method within the code allows you to adjust whether iterations begin with a one or a zero.

- GetTicks() is great if you want to e.g. number your results,
- DivisibleBy() returns a boolean result that you can use it in your own logic, and
- ConditionalOuput() will print out the text should the statement hold. Use reverse so the output is when the row is not divisible.